# Unity ECS get entity transform

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-dots

Is there any way to get transform component from entity? I know, there is new library for it, cant find. I could find only Translation. Maybe it's related with another way of getting entities? Maybe with query.

Can anyone help. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ComponentDataFromEntity<Translation> allTranslations = GetComponentDataFromEntity<Translation>(true);
```

....

```
public class TargetToDirectionSystem : SystemBase
{
    protected override void OnUpdate()
    {
        Entities.
            WithNone<PlayerTag>().
            WithAll<ChaserTag>().
            ForEach((ref MoveData moveData, ref Rotation rot, in Translation pos, in TargetData targetData) =>
            {
                ComponentDataFromEntity<Translation> allTranslations = GetComponentDataFromEntity<Translation>(true);
                if (!allTranslations.Exists(targetData.targetEntity))
                {
                    return;
                }

                Translation targetPos = allTranslations[targetData.targetEntity];
                float3 dirToTarget = targetPos.Value - pos.Value;
                moveData.direction = dirToTarget;

            }).Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a "transform" like the one that gameobjects have, but I suspect you're looking for LocalToWorld.  Along with having a position property, it has things like Rotation, Up, Forward, etc.  And it contains a matrix that you can use to multiply with a position to convert to to world coordinates.  If you want to go from world to local, invert the matrix before doing the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalToWorld` is a world transform. Both `Translation` and `Rotation` are local space.

```
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Jobs;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using Unity.Transforms;

float3 point = new float3( 0 , 0 , 0 );
Entities
    .ForEach( ( in LocalToWorld transform ) =>
    {
        float dist = math.distance( point , transform.Position );
        if( dist<5 )
        {
            /* something happens */
        }
    } )
    .WithBurst().ScheduleParallel();
```